# Modificar un recurso String en string.xml desde codigo (Kotlin o Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy desarrollando una App de cuestionario, Y en ella tengo una sección donde podría modificar las preguntas que se hacen, el problema es, que las preguntas estan almacenadas en el archivo strings.xml, sé como lograr mostrar lo que tienen, pero necesito es guardar el texto modificado en la misma referencia, ejemplo:
Tengo esta referencia en strings.xml

```
<string name="Sec1_Pregunta_One">Al pensar en su experiencia más reciente con NOMBRE EMPRESA, ¿cómo fue la calidad de servicio al cliente que recibió?</string>
```

La idea es que desde la misma App pueda modificar este String para cambiarle el 'NOMBRE EMPRESA', y que cuando vuelva a ver el cuestionario se vea el cambio

o sino se puede hacer, ¿De que otra manera podría hacerlo?

Comment: no se pueden modificar los valores de string.xml. Como obtendrías el 'NOMBRE EMPRESA'?

Comment: @armen Entonces de que otra manera podría hacerlo?

Comment: @josemanuelgutierrezsossa si es una cantidad considerable de preguntas puedes considerar usar una Base de datos, de otra forma podría ser un archivo que contenga las preguntas o preferencias.

Comment: Saludos @josemanuelgutierrezsossa te comento que colocar cerrada y la *respuesta* en el cuerpo de tu pregunta, si ya obtuviste la solución entonces por favor  considera publicarla abajo en la zona para ello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los recursos definidos dentro del directorio `/res` no pueden de ninguna forma ser modificados ya que son únicamente para lectura.

```
MyProject/
    src/
        MyActivity.java
    res/
        drawable/
            graphic.png
        layout/
            main.xml
            info.xml
        mipmap/
            icon.png
        values/
            strings.xml
```

[Información general sobre los recursos de las aplicaciones](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=es-419)

Si lo que deseas es modificar información, te sugiero alguna de las opciones de almacenamiento en Android:

[Descripción general del almacenamiento de archivos y datos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419)

> - **Almacenamiento interno:** Sirve para almacenar archivos privados de aplicaciones en el sistema del dispositivo.
> - **Almacenamiento externo:** Sirve para almacenar archivos en un sistema externo compartido. Se usa principalmente para archivos que comparte
>     el usuario, como fotos.
> - **Preferencias compartidas:** Sirve para almacenar datos privados de primitivas en pares clave-valor.
> - **Base de datos:** Sirve para almacenar datos estructurados en una base de datos privada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más que se puede hacer en el código es obtener la información por un getString de la siguiente forma:

```
**Java**
String string = getString(R.string.hello);

**Kotlin**
val string: String = getString(R.string.hello)
```

Para más información y uso de arreglos, te dejo más documentación, pero esencia no he podido encontrar como cambiar el string desde el código:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource?hl=es-419#kotlin

Comment: Hola Adriel, si te fijas, la pregunta tiene tres años de antiguedad, no vale la pena que te esfuerces en darle respuesta, por otro la do tu respuesta no parece solucionar el problema, te sugiero que la elimines, para evitar recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.
Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!